# Schengen visa denied because of fake bank statement

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas, deception, kenyan-citizens

I applied for a Schengen visa to travel to Germany and I was refused because of fake bank statement. Now I am worried that I will never be able to enter any Schengen countries. Is there any way to fix the damage done if I apply for another visa?

Comment: By writing a fake letter of apology? More seriously, why did you need to fake a bank statement?

Comment: You are in a fix. If the visa application asks "Have you ever been refused a visa?" you either have to lie again, risking another refusal, or expose yourself as a previous liar.

Comment: @Weather Vane The Schengen visa application does not ask that question.

Comment: @greatone: Which doesn't really matter, because the refusal will be registered in VIS (the Schengen-wide database of visa decisions), and come up by itself when he applies again.

Comment: @Henning Makholm The data on the VIS is retained for a maximum of five years.

Comment: Are you sure box #1 was checked as the reason? And are you sure the bank statement was fake? How do you know it was the bank statement? Did they include a custom letter in addition to the standard refusal form?

Answer (score 6):

- Be perfectly honest in all future applications. They will be suspicious of anything you write or say.
- Do not reapply anytime soon.
- Consult a lawyer before your next application.
- Do not reapply until your financial situation (along with lifestyle and personal circumstances) are **really** stable. Provide genuine documents of a stable job in your home country and an income which makes it easy for you to afford the trip.

Comment: Also, consider proactively explaining what was up with the fake bank statement, in your next visa application. You can't expect to be given an opportunity to explain yourself later in the process.

Comment: Is there really a chance of getting a visa after deception?

Comment: @greatone, I wrote *not anytime soon*. As I understand it, there can be visa even after deportation, but that won't be easy.

Comment: time cures everything. In 10 years the OP should be able to get a visa, using genuine documents, that is.

Comment: @greatone a dramatic change in personal circumstances can work. It's a question in its own right and might be well received on the site.